# netcat not able to run in windows 10

Tags: netcat

When I type ***nc -l -p 9999*** under the `nc.exe` bash, I got an error saying:

```
nc:forward host lookup failed: h_errno 11001: HOST_NOT_FOUND
```

The operating system of mine is Windows 10. This command works perfect in my friend's windows 7 computer which makes me think maybe there should have some more actions on windows 10?

I saw someone says to turn off the firewall, I did but it is still not working.

Hope somebody can help me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out. The thing is, you should just go to the netcat folder and type the command above. What I did before is to first execute the nc64.exe and then type the command inside the nc64.exe which causes the problem.

However, what I wrote above is only for windows. Mac, Linux does not apply.

Comment: I'm trying to run "nc -lk 9999" command to initiate spark streaming networkwordcount but I face with the invalid -k option error.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was doing this (**c:\users...\netcat** is the folder i've uncompressed nc.exe into):

```
c:\users\...\netcat> .\nc.exe
Cmd line: -l -p 10514
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hCVR.png)